# protobuf : The object created by add has the same member

Tags: c++, protobuf-c

This is the proto：

```
message GetIdKeyValueResp {
  optional int32 ret = 1;
  repeated IpInfo ips = 2;
}

message IpInfo {
  optional string ip = 1;
  optional string status = 2;
  optional uint64 update_time = 3;
  optional Disks disks = 4;
}

message DiskHistory {
  optional uint64 time = 1;
  optional string status = 2;
}

message Disk {
  optional uint32 index = 1;
  optional string status = 2;
  optional uint64 time = 3;
  repeated DiskHistory history = 4;
}

message Disks {
  optional int32 disk_num = 1;
  repeated Disk disk = 2;
}
```

And when I run the code

```
  GetIdKeyValueResp resp;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    IpInfo* ipinfo = resp.add_ips();
    cout << &(ipinfo->disks()) << endl;
  }
```

The output is:

```
0x6424880
0x6424880
0x6424880
0x6424880
0x6424880
0x6424880
0x6424880
0x6424880
0x6424880
0x6424880
```

Obviously they shared an address, so when I modify the disks information of one of the ips, the other ips will also be modified.I want to know why this is and how to solve it.

Comment: You have not added disks yet, you have created references to the default empty Disk record. Disks are created on modifications (copy on write).

Comment: Then how should I add disks?

Answer (score 1):

I use mutable_disks() and its ok